# How to count Sass mixin variable arguments

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to write a SASS mixin that outputs something different depending on how many variable arguments there are. Is there a way to count the number of arguments passed to a mixin?

```
@mixin my_func( $args... ) {
    @if count($args) === 4 {
        ... output here ...
    }

    @else {
        ... output here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`length`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#length) function:

```
@mixin my_func( $args... ) {
    @if length($args) == 4 {
        ... output here ...
    }

    @else {
        ... output here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah man. I was so close!  Thanks for your help